# What's the best way to globally access only specific indexes/keys of an array variable?

Tags: php, arrays, global-variables

I have an array

```
$user = array(
    "name" => "John Doe",
    "age" => "26",
    "country" => "US",
    "city" => "LA"
);
```

I want to access the variable's key "age" in a function. I'm currently using this:

```
global $user;
return $user['age'];
```

But I wonder if this is more efficient:

```
$age = $GLOBALS['user']['age'];
return $age;
```

Which one is best if you want to globally access only specific indexes/keys of an array variable?

Comment: What kind of `function`? Closure?

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions Nope, just a regular function.

Comment: You can use an static register class. Then you only have to do sonething like `Register::get('user.age');` But depends on your implementaion.  Mostly efficient `return $GLOBALS['user']['age'];` ;-)  But this is just micro-optimizing#

Comment: Is the Register class built-in PHP or do I need to create it?

Comment: Nope, but look here https://github.com/domnikl/DesignPatternsPHP/blob/master/Structural/Registry/Registry.php  and check the other DesignPatternsPHP therer too. You can make your kown simple registry from that information.